# Getting NULL Value in ifnull() instead of set value

Tags: apache-spark, if-statement, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do the majority of my work in SparkSQL so I'm trying to figure out a solution using just sparksql.

Goal I'm trying to achieve is:
When Src_Column2 = 'Hello' then load Target_Column as Src_Column1 else set Target_column = 0.00

So I tried but it loads the column as NULL is the condition isn't met:

```
(SELECT FIRST(IFNULL(Src_Column1, '0.00'))
FROM dfLookup Src_Table_1
WHERE     Src_Column2 = 'Hello')
AS Target_Column
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have null value instead of `NULL` literal string?

Comment: `if(Src_Column2='Hello', Src_Column1, '0.00') as Target_Column`

Comment: If you could provide enough information for us to reproduce your problem (sample data for a start), that would be great.

Comment: @Shu
I am getting null, sorry for the cap locks. 

I want to say thank you to all of you for help. Will post the solution soon.